# Getting Envelope Values From Extent using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, extents

Using following ArcPy snippet, I am able to get Extent of current map

```
import arcpy  
import arcpy.mapping  

## Sets the MXD file  
IMXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
## Sets the Dataframe  
DF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(IMXD, "Layers")[0]  

print DF.extent
```

as:

> 417939.472327849 241487.977474999 477757.540444938 363798.333225001 NaN NaN NaN NaN

can you please let me know how I can grab the Envelop value from This?

Comment: it's a list of doubles! XMin = DF.extent[0], YMin = DF.extent[1] etc.. see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000072000000 which values are you *really* after an what format do you need them in?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I think its an Extent rather than List object that gets returned by the DataFrame's extent property.

Comment: Yes @PolyGeo, there's a subtle difference. The extent property/object can be indexed like a list but also has properties (XMin, YMin etc.. as seen in your answer). I meant to say 'You can treat it like a list of doubles' though that could be dangerous - there's no guarantee in future releases indexing like a list will be accessible but the properties of an extent object are more likely to be future proof. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DataFrame class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm) has an `extent` property that returns an [Extent object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/extent.htm).  That Extent object has properties like `XMin`, `YMin`, `XMax` and `YMax` that return doubles and enable you to format your envelope.

To help understand what that means try adding this at the end of your code:

```
print("XMin: {0}, YMin: {1}".format(DF.extent.XMin, DF.extent.YMin))
print("XMax: {0}, YMax: {1}".format(DF.extent.XMax, DF.extent.YMax))
```